# How to use 'find' to print only matching directories?

Tags: bash, find

I am trying to use `find` to recursively search the file names in a directory for a particular pattern (wp-config.*).  When I do so using:

```
find `wp-config.*`
```

it seems to print all directories to the screen.  How can I ensure that only the matching directories are printed to the screen?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you really used `\``?

Comment: Are you backticks and a glob to find the paths for `find` to search?

Comment: @choroba Yes.  I tried using double-quotes, but was met with an error.  So I tried back-ticks and that's what resulted in every path name printed.  Do you know how to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 1):

Correct usage of find:

```
find -type d -name "wp-config.*"
```

The '-type d' will give you the directories.
The '-name "wp-config.*"' will give you the names requested.

Always use the man pages to search up commands. In this case:

```
man find
```

One last thing. The backticks ` are serving a totally different purpose. What you need here are regular quotes ".

Comment: Thanks.  I tried your command, but it did not seem to return anything (screenshot:  https://imgur.com/ADkVOEg).  Do I need to pipe the results to a file or stdout?  

Before posting I tried looking through the man page on find (https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ufind.htm).  It was quite lengthy, a bit difficult to understand at my level, and difficult to find the information I needed.

And good to know about the back-ticks.  I initially tried using the double quotes, but it returned an error, so I simply tried the back ticks and they were what resulted in the printing of all directories.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood your initial question.

Answer (score 1):

From the answers in [this outside post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/73zyyx/how_to_use_find_to_print_only_matching_directories/), I was able to use this command to do what I want:

```
find . -name 'wp-config.*' -printf "%h\n"
```

One of my main issues was that I originally did not understand that `find` does not print results to the screen. So it is necessary to pipe results to some kind of output.